# Gc using type information

Tags: algorithm, garbage-collection

Does anyone know of a GC algorithm which utilises type information to allow incremental collection, optimised collection, parallel collection, or some other nice feature?

By type information, I mean real semantics. Let me give an example: suppose we have an OO style class with methods to maintain a list which hide the representation. When the object becomes unreachable, the collector can just run down the list deleting all the nodes. It knows they're all unreachable now, because of encapsulation. It also knows there's no need to do a general scan of the nodes for pointers, because it knows all the nodes are the same type.

Obviously, this is a special case and easily handled with destructors in C++. The real question is whether there is way to analyse types used in a program, and direct the collector to use the resulting information to advantage. I guess you'd call this a *type directed garbage collector*.

Comment: You could statically determine you could delete all the pairs/nodes in the list by looking at liveness, but not the actual elements if the class had a get() method.

Comment: I don't know much about other GC-using languages, but I assume their approach is similar to JAva's: you pay the price of a GC in return for not having to deal with dead pointers. If you base your GC on anything but actual reference counts, you've lost the advantage and still have to pay the price. However, I could imagine type information driving a heuristic for deciding which object's reachability to check next.

Comment: I can imaging heuristics derived from type information too: that's the actual question, do you know of any actual heuristics :)

Answer (score 5):

The idea of at least exploiting containers for garbage collection in some way is not new, though in Java, you cannot generally assume that a container holds the only reference to objects within it, so your approach will not work in that context.

Here are a couple of references. One is for leak detection, and the other (from my research group) is about improving cache locality.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4814126
http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/06-06.pdf

You might want to visit Richard Jones's [extensive garbage collection bibliography](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/rej/gcbib/) for more references, or ask the folks on [gc-list](http://lists.tunes.org/mailman/listinfo/gclist).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with a specific algorithm.

When the GC computes the graph of objects relationship, the information that a `Collection` object is sole responsible for those elements of the list is implicitly present in the graph if the compiler was good enough to extract it.

Whatever the GC algorithm chosen: the information depends more on how the compiler/runtime will extract this information.

Also, I would avoid C and C++ with GC. Because of pointer arithmetic, aliasing and the possibility to point within an object (reference on a data member or in an array), it's incredibly hard to perform accurate garbage collection in these languages. They have not been crafted for it.

Comment: The list collection was only an example. The information that an object is responsible for the elements can be seen from a run time graph at a particular time, although the cost of analysing this is as high as just doing the collection, however there's no assurance this will always be the case for that object or others of its type. That is the point really. In this case you could use type information to tell the GC *not* to scan the container, and use a destructor when the container is deleted instead. How to do this more systematically?

Comment: WRT C/C++: these are prime candidates for a GC IMHO, *because* of dangling pointer problems. However my application is a C++ code generator, not hand written C++ code, so the situation is slightly different.

Comment: FYI: detecting interior pointer is extremely cheap using JudyArray, in fact there is almost no additional cost over detecting a head pointer. My method is faster the that used in the Boehm collector.

Comment: Actually, you can trivially detect interior pointers in O(1) time by using the right heap organization. See my paper for details: http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/06-28.pdf

Comment: @Emery: very interesting read thanks, I think I am going to spend some time on your papers.

Comment: @Emery: yes, interesting, though I'm not entirely convinced. For example if I allocate an array of 1020 bytes, I'll actually get 1024 bytes, there's no protection for improper writes to the last 4 bytes, correct? And so, if we have many pages of (say) 24 bytes objects, how do we discover they're 24 byte objects? Don't we still have to search the page directory?

Comment: Arg, scrub that second comment, I understand now (there's a 1-1 correspondence between data pages and index pages so the size information can be obtained by just right shifting the candidate pointer n bits.